# Create Vim file type for beamer presentations that modifies tex file type based on file extension and content of first few lines

Tags: vim, tex, beamer, file-type

When I write beamer tex slide presentations, I have developed a few modifications to the `tex` filetype that I would like to operate by default on beamer documents.

When I create a beamer document it has a `.tex` file extension and a line something like the following in the first few lines:

```
\documentclass[...]{beamer}
```

For simplicity, we could say that any file with a `.tex` extension and the text `beamer` anywhere in the first 5 lines should default to filetype `beamer`.

- How could I automatically set the filetype to `beamer` using both information from the file extension and the initial few lines of the file?

As often happens, the process of formulating the question has led me to `:h new-filetype-scripts`, but this still requires a fair amount of deciphering. Any tips would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

According to the help article you pointed out, you need to create a
`scripts.vim` file in your vim runtime directory with content that looks like
this:

```
if did_filetype()
  finish
endif

if expand('%:e') == 'tex'
  for n in range(1, 5)
    if getline(n) =~ 'beamer'
      setfiletype beamer
      break
    endif
  endfor
endif
```

Interestingly enough, this doesn't work for me. I managed to do it by putting it in `ftplugin/beamer.vim` and changing it a bit to the following:

```
for n in range(1, 5)
  if getline(n) =~ 'beamer'
    set filetype=beamer
    break
  endif
endfor
```

Whenever the `tex` filetype gets loaded, the beamer-specific stuff gets sourced as well. I'd recommend trying the `scripts.vim` approach first, and consider the second one if you can't get it working that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still experimenting but a preliminary solution seems to be to add a file called `beamer.vim` to `~/.vim/ftdetect` with the following command:

```
au BufRead,BufNewfile *.tex if getline(1) =~ 'beamer' | set filetype=beamer.tex | endif
```

Note, I've simplified the command slightly from specifications above, and  filetype `beamer.tex` incorporates both the tex features and my beamer customisations.